# filterning by many fields when some are optional in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to filter my table by 3 fields BUT all the three are optional i can search by one field or two or three. At least one field should be set.

This what i reached , This code works perfectly fine for one field and if i add the other fields this way THEY SHOULD BE SET. How can i introduce the optionality ?

```
    $('#submitButton').click(function() {
    var quantity = $("[name='quantity']").val();
    var category = $('select.categorylist option:selected').val();
    var brand = $("[name='brand']").val();

     $("table tbody tr").hide();

    $("table tbody tr").each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).find("td:eq(3):contains('" + quantity + "')").html() != null)
                {
                    $(this).show();
                }
         });
    return false ; 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` function like this:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() {

    var quantity = $("[name='quantity']").val(),
        category = $('select.categorylist option:selected').val(),
        brand = $("[name='brand']").val();

    $("table tbody tr:not(.header, .filters)").hide().filter(function() {
        var q = quantity ? this.cells[0].innerHTML === quantity : true,
            c = category ? this.cells[1].innerHTML === category : true,
            b = brand ? this.cells[2].innerHTML === brand : true;
        return q && c && b;
    }).show();

    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v4HYP/

So row will be shown only if each column's value matches corresponding filter.

Comment: Something strange is happening actually . Can you explain the logic behind it ? 
If the 3rd filter is only set its not working . While if the 2nd is set and the 3rd is set its working

Comment: `quantity ? this.cells[1].innerHTML === quantity : true` If `quantity` is defined (not empty) then for each row check the first `td` if it's content equals to `quantity` varable. Otherwise set `q` to true. It means that this row will be hidden.